# error while loading xib file from tableview in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitableview

i am trying to make an app in which i use tableview.

I am populating the tableview and i am able to display data in the table. Now what i am trying to do is when i click a specific cell in the tableview i want to load a particular xib file in different folder. For all other cell i want to load second tableview. i am using a storyboard.

i am using

```
(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([((UITableViewCell *)sender).textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"ABCD"]) {
    ABCD *abcdViewController = [[ABCD alloc] initWithNibName:@"ABCD" bundle:nil];

    // Push the view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ABCDViewController animated:YES];
}
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
NSLog(@"%@", ((UITableViewCell *)sender).textLabel.text);

MethodsViewController *methodsViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

NSString *rowTitle = ((UITableViewCell *)sender).textLabel.text;
NSDictionary *selected = [[self methodsDict] objectForKey:rowTitle];

methodsViewController.rows = [selected objectForKey:@"rows"];
methodsViewController.methodsDict = [selected objectForKey:@"methodsDict"];
}
```

This is the code i am using. i made this code after searching the internet.

but the problem is

but when i build and run this the first tableview is shown and when i click on the ABCD cell the xib loads but the navigation bar is covering the upper portion of the xib file and when i click on the back button in the navigation bar it takes me to the black blank page and shows a error

***nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar***

***Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.***

and the app stops

I dont know what i am doing wrong i am new to ios

I hope you understand my problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least three possible approaches to what you are trying to do.

The easiest one is using `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:` to control exactly when segueing as specified in IB and when pushing your ABCD view controller instead:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender{

  if ([((UITableViewCell *)sender).textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"ABCD"]) {
    ABCD *abcdViewController = [[ABCD alloc] initWithNibName:@"ABCD" bundle:nil];

    // Push the view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ABCDViewController animated:YES];
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

This should work pretty easily for you, since it is similar to what you have been trying to do with `prepareForSegue:`. The fault with your current approach using `prepareForSegue:` is that you are both pushing your ABCD controller and doing the segue. `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:` allows you to cancel the segue, so to say, when you are going to push manually.

Another approach would be using **manual segues**:

- you can create a manual segue in IB by dragging from the view controller (as opposed to dragging from the prototype table cell); you can create multiple named segues;
- in your table view delegate you override `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` so that it calls `performSegueWithIdentifier:`:

  ```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  

       NSString *identifierOfSegueToCall;
       UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nowIndex];

       if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"ABCD"]) {
           identifierOfSegueToCall = @"ABCDSegueIdentifier";
       } else {
           identifierOfSegueToCall = @"XYWZCellSegueIdentifier";
       }

       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:identifierOfSegueToCall sender:self];
   }
  ```

Finally, a third approach would be defining two **different cell prototypes** for your table view and segueing from each prototype cell into the appropriate view controller. This is similar to what you have already done for setting up your current segue, only you should add a new prototype cell and define a specific segue from it.

Comment: so i have to use (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender instead of (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility, returning `NO` when you manually push.

Comment: so i have to use if condition inside this function??

Comment: what i am doing is in if(){#the things you said} and in else i am using the before said code(which i was using) but i get segue not defined. i know this is basic question but i am new to ios pls help..

Comment: got it..i am using both function shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier and prepareForSegue..thanks man..u rock